# Why is the Third Man fielding position in Cricket called "Third Man"?

Tags: cricket, terminology

As a cricket fan from India, I mostly know about everything there is to know about cricket. Except why a fielding position, Third Man, located behind the batsman
on the right side(off side) near the boundary, is called "Third Man".

Also, two other positions, namely Gully (between slips & point) & silly mid-on/mid-off. Why Silly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by no means definitive, but this [link](http://historyofcricket.blogspot.ie/2007/12/derivations-of-cricketing-terms.html) states that it's because, when overarm bowling was introduced, another fielder (to complement slip and point) was needed - this was the third fielder, hence third man.

This [link](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/sunday-times/Why-is-the-third-man-called-so/articleshow/39702002.cms), however, gives a subtly different interpretation.

The first link also gives these explanations:

> Gully - Refers to the gap or 'gully' that exists between the slips and
>   point
>
> Cover - Refers to the position that 'covers' the point and middle of
>   the wicket
>
> Mid off and mid on - Shortenings of the terms 'middle wicket off' and
>   'middle wicket on'
>
> Silly Mid On - the mid on is self explanatory, however it is believed
>   that the silly refers to an old definition of silly, meaning
>   'defenceless'.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard a different explanation for Third Man, which is that there are three 'stopping' positions 'wicket-keeper', 'long stop', and 'third man' behind the wicket.